# Join two collections with like operation(where n1.mobileno like n2.code+'%') in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
select ndnc.mobileno,ndnc.opstype,n.Destination_Code_Domestic_Format,n.circle from ndncincremental ndnc,numberingrange n where ndnc.mobileno like n.destination_code_domestic_format + '%' and n.circle='delhi' and ndnc.opstype='d'
```

I want this SQL query in MongoDB